# Solving system of equations for trig problem in Wolfram Alpha

Tags: wolfram-alpha

**I'm new to Wolfram Alpha.**  I'm trying to learn how to do solving using a basic trig system of equations but I don't understand the ouput.

The problem is stated in graphic below, I want to solve for t in degrees.

I've tried this input in Alpha, in the Natural Language mode:

> solve[cos(t deg) = x/L, L=1, x=0.75, t]

I expected the output to include t = 41 degrees, but it does not.

Thanks for any assistance

[image]

Comment: Try a different input, like [solve cos(t deg) = x/L when L=1, x=0.75](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve%5Bcos%28t+deg%29+%3D+x%2FL%5D+when+L%3D1%2C+x%3D0.75). Also, if you feel strongly that your input should be interpreted in a specific way, you can contact the WA team by submitting feedback

Answer (score 1):

Either bracket the three conditions to separate them from the variables, or you can delete the variable part:

> solve[cos(t deg) = x/L, L=1, x=0.75]

To see the numerical results, In the solutions part, click "Approximate forms".